# Another android app overwrites my keydown listener

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

My application uses Cordova. I have a plugin that is triggered when I press a button called SCAN on my PDA which has Android 2.3. When I press this button turns the laser and scans a barcode. The problem is that when I open another application in the background that has this function, when I press the SCAN button starts that application and not my code from my application.

I think that other applications that start this hardware resource (scanner) have a higher priority and overrides my key event of my application. Is there any possibility that my application have higher priority?

I run this code from my cordova plugin when I press SCAN button:

```
Intent intentScan = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
intentScan.putExtra("scan_mode", 5);
startActivityForResult(this, intentScan, 0);
```

And this is my keylistener from javascript:

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 0 && e.keyIdentifier == "U+000000") {
        datawedge.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: The other application has an intent filter for "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" which triggers the start of the application. Define the same intenet filter in your manifest and your device will ask you which application should react on that intenet.

Comment: I tried keyup. That application still overwrites my code.

Comment: I have 2 applications that came with PDA:
- **Scantool** which starts when I press SCAN in my application;
- **Scanwedge** waiting to make a textbox focus. When you are in a textbox and you press Scan, this application starts without asking. Probably uses another package. So, intent filter does not help.

Comment: It would be great if I had a code to check if scanwedge is enabled. If it is active, then disable it.